# ContextMenu Showing at left top corner of the Desktop for the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I am showing a customized context menu on mouse right buttonup  and placed it by adding below code snippet:

```
MyCustomContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint
```

Always t for the first time the context menu is showing at the left top corner of the Desktop, after that it is showing at mouse cursor point. Anyone know what might be the issue with the context menu? Whether I am doing any mistake any where? Do I need to set any property any where? Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I do not know why it is, But the below try worked for me.

**Try:-** At the initialize time you set the `PlacementMode` as `Mouse` i.e.

```
MyCustomContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse;
```

and later at the time of opening and showing `ContextMenu` on `RightMouseButtonUp`
you change the PlacementMode by

```
MyCustomContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint;
```

It worked for me, check whether its working for you or not.Good Luck.

Comment: Yeah you are correct it is also working for me. But can you tell me why is it behaving like that. Even I tried with assigning the PlacementMode as MousePoint at the Initialization time and that also did not work for me. It is only working if I use the sequence and values as you told .